# Compile-Time Polymorphism for Data Members

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++11

In the following code, `initialize()` illustrates a method based on compile-time polymorphism.  The version of `initialize()` compiled depends on `int2type<true>` and `int2type<false>`, only one of which will be true for a given template parameter `T`.

It just so happens that data member `T* m_datum;` will work for both `int2type<true>` and `int2type<false>`.

Now, I want to change the `int2type<false>` version to `std::vector<T> m_datum;`, so my question is, **how do I modify my code so that the data member `m_datum` is polymorphic on `int2type<>`?**

Note: please ignore the rationale behind the code below - instead, I would like to focus on the mechanics of achieving compile-time polymorphism for data members.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template <bool n>
struct int2type
{
  enum { value = n };
};

template< typename T >
struct is_trivially_copyable
{
  static const bool value = std::is_standard_layout<T>::value;
};

template<class T>
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo( size_t n ) : m_nr( n )
    {
      initialize( int2type<is_trivially_copyable<T>::value>() );        
    }
    ~Foo() { }

  private:
    void initialize( int2type<true> )
    {
      m_datum = (T*) calloc( sizeof(T), m_nr );
    }
    void initialize( int2type<false> )
    {
      m_datum = new T[m_nr];
    }

  private:
     size_t     m_nr;
     T*         m_datum;   // ok for int2type<true>
 //  vector<T>  m_datum;   // want to change to this for int2type<false>
};

class Bar
{
  public:
    Bar() { }
    virtual ~Bar() { }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Foo<int> foo_trivial(     5 );
  Foo<Bar> foo_nontrivial( 10 );

  return 0;
}
```

**C++11 solution, based on Nawaz's recommendations**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

template< typename T >
struct is_trivially_copyable
{
    static const bool value = std::is_standard_layout<T>::value;
};

template<class T>
class Foo
{
    private:
        static const bool what = is_trivially_copyable<T>::value;
        typedef typename std::conditional<what,T*,std::vector<T>>::type type;

    public:
        Foo( size_t n ) : m_nr( n )
        {
            initialize( m_datum );      
        }
        ~Foo() { }

    private:
        void initialize( T* dummy )
        {
            m_datum = (T*) calloc( sizeof(T), m_nr );
        }
        void initialize( std::vector<T>& dummy )
        {
            m_datum.resize( m_nr );             
        }

    private:
        size_t     m_nr;
        type       m_datum;   
};

class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar()  { }
        virtual ~Bar() { }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo<int> foo_trivial(     5 );
    Foo<Bar> foo_nontrivial( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**C++11 Solution**

Use [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) as:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class Foo
{
  //some info we can use throughout the class
  static const bool what = is_trivially_copyable<T>::value;
  typedef typename std::conditional<what, T*, std::vector<T>>::type data_type;

  //data members
  data_type m_data;  //this is what you need!
}
```

---

**C++03 Solution**

You can write a metafunction and partially specialize  this as follows:

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
     //primary template
     template<bool b, typename T> 
     struct get { typedef T* type; };

     //partial specialization
     template<typename T> 
     struct get<false, T> { typedef std::vector<T> type; };

     //some info we can use throughout the class
     static const bool what = is_trivially_copyable<T>::value;
     typedef typename get<what, T>::type data_type;

     //data members
     data_type m_data;  //this is what you need!
};
```

So when `what` is `true`, `data_type` will turn out to be `T*`, or else it will be `std::vector<T>`, as desired.

In either case, you don't need `int2type` class template. Just remove that from your code. You can write cleaner code, without it.

Comment: it's more conventional to use `type` instead of `data_type`

Comment: +1: For knowing the standard library of the upcoming standard already, plus for encouraging cleaner code by sidestepping the OP's `int2type<>` detour.

Comment: great solution - trying to recode the OP without `int2type<>` now, for clarity and for future reference

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
// Generic
template <typename T, typename Arg>
struct datum_type_dispatch {};

// Specialization for Arg = int2type<true>
template <typename T>
struct datum_type_dispatch<T, int2type<true> >
{
    typedef T* type;
};

// Specialization for Arg = int2type<false>
template <typename T>
struct datum_type_dispatch<T, int2type<false> >
{
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    // ...
private:
    // Get the datum type based on int2type<...>
    typedef typename datum_type_dispatch<T, int2type<is_trivially_copyable<T>::value> >::type datum_type;

    datum_type m_datum;
};
```